# Recipe for Brewing?

Tags: beer, recipe

I am just getting into brewing, I have used Fiesta Brew kits, from Canada, and produced some decent beers. I am looking to learn the complete science behind brewing and have done some research and began reading a few books to help with guidance.

I was wondering if I could get some suggestions on some recipes, for various beer types that are fully brewed at home. The kits are great, don't get me wrong but I am looking for a more involved brewing process.

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Mat

Answer (score 6):

I will warn you to be leery of a lot of recipe sites on the internet.  Some are good, some are very bad and you have to know what looks like a good recipe in order to separate them from the bad ones.  That said, about the best internet resource for recipes I've found is http://wiki.homebrewersassociation.org/BeerRecipes .

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will definately pay close attention to them. I am going to do some research and will use the website you have suggested as well. Thanks Denny, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

I would guess that the books you're reading will include some recipes.  If not, then check out the book "How to Brew" by John Palmer (available online for free, or to purchase in hard copy):

http://www.howtobrew.com/

Answer (score 1):

I have used this with good success http://www.byo.com/store?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage.tpl&product_id=94&category_id=16 There are good clone recipes in it so I feel that I can really get a good idea of how close my technique comes to the real thing. Also many of the recipes have been compiled from help from the master brewers that have crafted them. I am also pretty sure that there may be some in there from you neck of the woods.

 
 The really neat things is that 99% of the recipes have all grain and extract versions so you can brew them all to your skill/equipment level.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the suggestions, I will definately use them. As the knowldge grows, I am understanding more and want to apply that knowldge to the recipes of brewing but I find some recipes good, but vague in that the procedures. Time will help me better understand the steps involved. Again, thank you for the time to help me out...

Comment: Yeah, spending some time learning from a good book, like John Palmer's, is a very important first step.  After you understand what it's all about, you'll be able to understand what to do for a recipe which doesn't include "procedures" details.

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree to be careful of "internet recipes", but that being said, there's good advice to be had at HomeBrewTalk.com. They have a fairly active recipe exchange forum, and generally the recipes there have been tried by a couple of folks - and usually if someone else attempts it, their feedback will be listed there as well.

In addition to the books listed above, I've also enjoyed [Extreme Brewing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1592532934) by Dogfish Head's Sam Calagione. Some of the DFH recipes are listed in that book, and the ones I've tried have been very good. Also, [Designing Great Beers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0937381500) is an excellent start for building your own recipes.

Finally, I've used the Northern Brewer site to look at their recipes (go to the page for the kit you're interested in, and choose the link for the Kit Inventory Sheet). From there, you can buy the kit as is, or tweak ingredients. Most of those recipes are tried and tested good beers (in my experience).

Comment: Excellent, thank you forthe insight. I am learning more and more and am always looking for new information and education. Muchly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think I'd recommend Extreme Brewing to someone looking to make recipes for the first time. Too many Frankensteins in there. Radical Brewing by Mosher would be a better choice.

Comment: There are "Frankensteins" for sure, but I bought it and brewed the 60 minute as my 4th brew. They're strange (and off-style) recipes, but they're not necessarily complicated. I was new to homebrewing, but have been a craft beer enthusiast for several, several years.

Answer (score 0):

We have listed a number of great books here, [What is the best book for beginning home brewers?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2121/what-is-the-best-book-for-beginning-home-brewers). Inside a number of these books are great recipes.